# Cakephp pagination sort by calculated field ( COUNT )

Tags: sorting, cakephp, count, pagination, aggregate-functions

I had a problem sorting a paginated list when using a calculated field such as COUNT() in cakephp 1.3

Let's say that i have two models: Article and Comments (1 article x N comments) and i want to display a paginated list of the articles including the number of comments for each one. I'd have something like this:

**Controller:**

```
$this->paginate = array('limit'=>80,
                        'recursive'=>-1,
                        'fields'=>array("Article.*","COUNT(Comment.id) as nbr_comments"),
                        'joins'=>array(array(   'table' => 'comments',
                                                    'alias' => 'Comment',
                                                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                                                    'conditions' => array('Comment.article_id = Article.id'))
                                            ),
                        'group'=>"Article.id"
                        );
```

(i had to overwrite the `findCount()` method in order to paginate using group by)

The problem is that in the view, the `sort()` method won't work:

```
<th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('nbr_comments');?></th> //life is not that easy
```

I was able to create a workaround by "cheating" the pagination and sort:

**Controller**

```
$order = "Article.title";
$direction = "asc";
if(isset($this->passedArgs['sort']) && $this->passedArgs['sort']=="nbr_comments")
    $order = $this->passedArgs['sort'];
    $direction = $this->passedArgs['direction'];
    unset($this->passedArgs['sort']);
    unset($this->passedArgs['direction']);
}
$this->paginate = array(... 'order'=>$order." ".$direction, ...);
$this->set('articles', $this->paginate());
if($order == "clicks"){
    $this->passedArgs['sort'] = $order;
    $this->passedArgs['direction'] = $direction;
}
```

**View**

```
<?php $direction = (isset($this->passedArgs['direction']) && isset($this->passedArgs['sort']) && $this->passedArgs['sort'] == "nbr_comments" && $this->passedArgs['direction'] == "desc")?"asc":"desc";?>
<th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Hits','clicks',array('direction'=>$direction));?></th>
```

And it works.. but it seems that is too much code for something that should be transparent to the developper. (It feels like i'm doing cake's work) So i'm asking if there's another simpler way. Maybe cake has this functionallity but decided to hide it.. o_O..  there's nothing about this on the documentation, and i haven't found another good solution on S.O... how do you do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

maybe your problem can be solved using [Virtual fields](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1608/Virtual-fields) ?

If you create a custom field for your computed field, you will be able to sort using Paginator->sort() method on that custom field.

I found that solution [there](http://abcoder.com/php/cakephp/cakephp-advanced-pagination-sort-by-derived-field/) in the comments (there is no need to customize the paginate method etc. using custom fields instead of in adnan's initial solution).

Comment: it certainly helps, =) with virtual fields i dont have to worry about the `$this->passedArgs` thanks... however, you still need to [override the paginateCount](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120257/cakephp-pagination-count-not-matching-query/7121798#7121798) method if you want to paginate the results

Comment: Another problem is that sometimes you will have to determine fields (conditions => fields) so a virtualfield won't be requested/gotten.

Because otherwise, the query might change. For instance with the virtualfield count(*) : the find method will always return only 1 row.

Comment: Didn't know about vitualFields, and now I do, and they do exactly what I needed.  Thanks!

Comment: That link to book.cakephp.org does not work anymore. Perhaps someone could elaborate on the code that was under that link?

Answer (score 2):

What you may want to do is use Cake's [counterCache](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1033/counterCache-Cache-your-count) functionality in your model definition.  Rather than calculating the comment counts at read time, you add `nbr_comments` as an int field in your `articles` table. Every time a `Comment` is inserted or deleted, `nbr_comments` will be updated automatically.

In your `Comment` model:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Article' => array(
        'counterCache' => 'nbr_comments'
    )
);
```

Now you can just use `$this->Paginator->sort('Article.nbr_comments');` You wont need to do anything funky in your controller.

Comment: but i'm afraid that if i add a calculated field in a db table, Codd's ghost will harass me at night XD... in this example i'm using only a COUNT by i already had some cases where I have a COUNT, an AVG, and a formula on the same query.. if i store that info on the DB i risk the data integrity

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this problem was the following:

put your calculate field as a virtual field

```
$this->Comment->virtualFields = array(
    'nbr_comments' => 'COUNT(Comment.id)'
);
```

then,  you can use that field, in your paginate order variable

```
$order = array("Comment.nbr_comments" => "DESC");
$this->Paginator->settings  = array("order" => $order);
```