# CakePHP Pagination count not matching query?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-1.3

I've got a fairly modified pagination query using a number of Joins etc - but for some reason the paginator->counter() never matches the results from the count query.

You can see it in action at http://dev.qreer.com/ - by choosing various options on the LHS navigation, the query output is below and the paginator count appears to be pretty random.

Any idea where I can start looking to debug this?

In the Jobs Controller:

```
    $this->paginate = $this->Job->paginateParams($data);
    $jobs = $this->paginate('Job');
    $this->set(compact('jobs'));
```

In the Model:

```
function paginateParams($data = null){
        //lots of joins + conditions
        return array('contain' => $contain, 'recursive' => 0,'joins' => $joins, 'conditions' => $conditions, 'group' => 'Job.id', 'order' => $order);
    }
```

Sample Join (there's inner joins for all the join tables and data tables):

```
        array(
            'table' => 'education_backgrounds',
            'alias' => 'EducationBackground',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array('EducationBackgroundsJobs.education_background_id = EducationBackground.id'),
        ),
```

Sample Condition:

```
      'EducationBackground.name' => array('Aerospace Engineering');
```

Comment: I ran into the same problem yesterday, it happens when you have a group in the pagination query. Didn't find a fix...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's because of the `group by` I found a workaround. I'd love to put the link but i've lost it, so i'll post the code:

```
public function paginateCount($conditions = null, $recursive = 0, $extra = array()) {
    $parameters = compact('conditions', 'recursive');
    if (isset($extra['group'])) {
        $parameters['fields'] = $extra['group'];
        if (is_string($parameters['fields'])) {
            // pagination with single GROUP BY field
            if (substr($parameters['fields'], 0, 9) != 'DISTINCT ') {
                $parameters['fields'] = 'DISTINCT ' . $parameters['fields'];
            }
            unset($extra['group']);
            $count = $this->find('count', array_merge($parameters, $extra));
        } else {
            // resort to inefficient method for multiple GROUP BY fields
            $count = $this->find('count', array_merge($parameters, $extra));
            $count = $this->getAffectedRows();
        }
    } else {
        // regular pagination
        $count = $this->find('count', array_merge($parameters, $extra));
    }
    return $count;
}
```

I added it in the app_model and it works fine for me :)

Hope this helps

**Edited:** I found the link =)

http://wiltonsoftware.com/posts/view/custom-group-by-pagination-and-a-calculated-field

Comment: Thanks! It's pretty much exactly what I worked out - but this is definitely the 'catch-all' solution.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

The paginator counter relies on `$this->find('count')` to return an integer of the total of the results, which for some reason, doesn't like the 'group' parameter. So following the [Custom Query Pagination](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1237/Custom-Query-Pagination) (which also recommends at the bottom of the page to do the count yourself for any custom / modified pagination) - I added the following to my model:

```
function paginateCount(){
    $params = Configure::read('paginate.params');
    $params['fields'] = 'DISTINCT (Job.id)';
    unset($params['group']);
    unset($params['contain']);
    unset($params['order']);
    return $this->find('count', $params);
}
```

This overwrites the value with the correct one and it all seems to be working perfectly.

Bearing in mind I've added `Configure::write('paginate', array('params' => $this->paginate['Job']));` to my controller so I can access the pagination parameters.

Answer (score 0):

function paginateCount($conditions = null, $recursive = 0,$extra) 
               {

```
                   $db = $this->getDataSource();
                           $sql = $db->buildStatement(
                                   array(
                                   'fields'     => array('DISTINCT Gdi.id'),
                                   'table'      => $db->fullTableName($this),
                                   'alias'      => 'Gdi',
                                   'limit'      => null,
                                   'offset'     => null,
                                   'joins'      => isset($extra['joins'])?$extra['joins']:null,
                                   'conditions' => $conditions,
                                   'order'      => null,
                                   'group'      =>isset($extra['group'])?$extra['group']:null
                                   ),
                           $this
                           );



                   $this->recursive = $recursive;
                   $results = $this->query($sql);

                   return count($results);
           }
```

Just add this function in your model and change the field name and model name. Using this function you can customize you own query count.